# What/Where is The Morgue?

Tags: toradora

During the Culture Festival in 2-C's wrestling show, when Taiga's  Mind-Controlled "lackeys" have the thread to Yuri Koigakubo's future boyfriend/husband and threaten to cut it, Yuri interrupts the performance and tries to stop them. When the other "lackeys" stop her they go to take her away from the stage and someone says to take her to The Morgue.

When Taiga is running for Student Council President as a means to try and provoke Yūsaku to run aswell she threatens to take everyone's dreams to The Morgue.

I get the feeling that this Morgue is some sort of reference but not the traditional sense of a The Morgue. so i am wondering, What/Where is The Morgue where Yuri was taken to and where Taiga threaten to take the student's dreams to.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not an extra reference to anything but a (possibly figurative) morgue.

In the first bit you mentioned, Taiga is doing the "evil overlord" character that Ami wrote for her, and the reference is pretty much a bowdlerized way to say they're killing Yuri-sensei.  The second time is just a callback to the first -- Taiga's character as "student council president who will destroy your happy school life" is very clearly just her going back to the character that Ami had written for her; since the Palmtop Tiger and Delinquent Ryuji were pretty much sticking with the characters that'd been established, she uses a lot of references to the wrestling act. (Plus I think it was fun for her to say "morgue".)